# Hiring a Third Party Developer, what config files & certificates are ok to share?

Tags: certificates, appsec, permissions, secret-sharing, third-party

So my cofounder and I hired a developer through Guru to build our native iOS and Android MVP's. Long story short, he agreed to integrate Firebase and BrainTree, and originally asked for our account credentials to both of those services so he could integrate everything. I saw this as a huge red flag (giving him our username and password???), but ultimately decided that he may have just assumed we weren't very tech savvy. I am a 4th year CS student, and have developed a fair amount of hackathon-scale projects. I figured that he should be able to develop everything on his own without any of our credentials or API keys, and we would just replace the Firebase configuration files and Apple permissions files (p12 and certificates) with our own when he finishes writing the logic for everything. Am I wrong? What types of files are safe/reasonable to send him for him to integrate everything? In the immediate term, is it safe to send him our p12 and certificate files?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're a small operation but you should still tried to seperate production from development and seperation of duties. A developer  **NEVER** needs to have access to any signing key or account related to production and hiring an external always adds a risk factor.

You should have spun him up an environment that you could throw away after his work and retain control of those you intended to use in production.

Comment: iOS and Xcode don't quite work that way as far as I know. I have the ability to revoke developer certificates, but the certificates are signed by my Mac so I'm not sure if these would be safe to share with him. Wouldn't it make more sense for him to have me sign his CSR (with my apple developer account)?